# Properties in Objective C - losing object pointer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the following property in my Objective C header file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyObj *myObj;
```

In the implementation (.m file), I have the following two methods:

```
-(void)setMyObj:(MyObj *)myObj {
    NSLog(@"set MyObj %@",myObj); //this is fine and not null
    _myObj = myObj;
}

-(MyObj *)getMyObj {
    NSLog(@"getting MyObj: %@",_myObj); //this prints (null)
    return _myObj; 
}
```

At some point I set the value of `myObj` and then soon after call `getMyObj`, and I do not touch the value of `myObj` in between (I don't access any of its variables or invoke methods on it or use it at all). Why is `myObj` `null` in the `getMyObj` method? I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I have defined the `myObj` property in the `.h` file.

Comment: Definition and setter/getter methods looks fine. Are you sure you are calling `set:` and `get` on the same object? Try changing your debug log to `NSLog(@"set MyObj %@ in %p",myObj, self);` and `NSLog(@"getting MyObj: %@ in %p",_myObj, self);` and see if the pointer is the same.

Comment: Also, is `MyObj *` just a typo?

Comment: getMyObj isn't fine. It should be myObj

Comment: @powerj1984 He says he calls `getMyObj`.

Comment: why do write the setter/getter? The property should be accessible, if it's declared in the header file.

Comment: The pointer's were indeed different. I fixed it :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @CodeGuy Added an answer. :-)

Comment: Good point, I didn't read clearly enough. To be clear though, this isn't idiomatic code. You should override the getter which is by default myObj, not getMyObj

Comment: Are you not using ARC? If are using it, you should change `retain` to `strong`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to call the setter and getter on the same object.